# Use case of .Net Bindable Property and Bindable Property Key

Tags: .net, xamarin

I'm studying [Xamarin Video Player code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/video-player/) and got confused by the use of BindableProperty and BindablePropertyKey.

Under what circumstances/use case do we use BindableProperty over BindablePropertyKey and vice versa. Are they both interchangeable?

Comment: Have a look at the [bindable-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) may help.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I understand how bindableproperty works. But I don't understand why do we need the bindablepropertykey.

Comment: The bindablepropertykey is used to [create a read-only bindable property](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=mUMNCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT311&lpg=PT311&dq=bindablepropertykey+and+bindableproperty&source=bl&ots=mM0XoqlBwR&sig=ACfU3U33vN0onPCBqjECLDfsAAtf6oC80w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG0dnom_nhAhVJHKYKHQdHCUAQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=bindablepropertykey%20and%20bindableproperty&f=false).